# Keeping an image centered, while maintaining 100% height and only extending/cropping the sides

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position

## The Problem

I have a user image, which I want to scale up and down with the window so that the height is always 100% and the image stays centered.

---

#### Example 1

This example scales as the window is resized, but the height doesn't stay at 100% and therefore gets cut off at the bottom.

```css
.user {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

[CodePen Example 1](https://codepen.io/polygami/pen/PQpKmV)

---

#### Example 2

This example works perfectly, apart from when the width of the browser window is smaller than the width of the image, the right-hand side is cut off.

I *do* want the image to be cropped, but I want the right and left sides to be cropped *equally*.

```css
.user {
    object-position: center;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[CodePen Example 2](https://codepen.io/polygami/pen/GQWvEw)

---

#### Visual Example

Here is an example of how I want the images to appear when the browser is scaled horizontally/vertically.

[image: myimage]

Comment: Congratulations! Neatly asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to use multiple background like this:

*I used multiple div to illustrate with different sizes*

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-shine {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%, cover;
  background-image: url("https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/512/user-male-icon.png"), url("https://t.motionelements.com/stock-video/design-elements/me1656952-blue-sunrise-background-hd-a0120-poster.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <div class="bg-shine" style="height:100px;width:400px;">

  </div>
  <div class="bg-shine" style="height:100px;width:200px;">

  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <div class="bg-shine" style="height:200px;width:100px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

To avoid using the image within CSS you can consider the inline style and a separate div for the user image so that you have almost the same markup as using an image tag:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-shine {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://t.motionelements.com/stock-video/design-elements/me1656952-blue-sunrise-background-hd-a0120-poster.jpg");
}

.bg-shine>div {
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <div class="bg-shine" style="height:100px;width:400px;">
    <div style="background-image:url('https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/512/user-male-icon.png')"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-shine" style="height:100px;width:200px;">
    <div style="background-image:url('https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/512/user-male-icon.png')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <div class="bg-shine" style="height:200px;width:100px;">
    <div style="background-image:url('https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/512/user-male-icon.png')"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect in terms of how I want it to look.

The only issue is that I want to have many different users being pulled in from a database and don't want to have to create a CSS rule for each of them.

I'll be using EJS to create an HTML template with embedded JavaScript.

I *could* do the style inline, but if there was a grid of multiple users, there would be a lot of code repetition.

I realise I didn't mention this in the original post. I will add this in now.

[Here is a version using multiple backgrounds](https://codepen.io/polygami/pen/xYqXjB)

Comment: @Polygami well by using the inline style you will have almost the same repetition as using url with image tag :) the only thing here is that it will be longer. but you can always split in two divs also ;) am gonna update

Comment: @Polygami i edited my answer you can check again :) you will have the same code as image tag ;)

Comment: I didn't think of that! That's much better and has almost the same amount of HTML.

[Correct working version](https://codepen.io/polygami/pen/zRZPBV)

Answer (score 0):

I like your question! I approached it from a different angle, and tried to use background rather than img element. Please see the results here:

https://codepen.io/Varin/pen/xYqXQe

```css
body, html {
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0;
}

.bg-shine {
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("http://t.motionelements.com/stock-video/design-elements/me1656952-blue-sunrise-background-hd-a0120-poster.jpg");
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/512/user-male-icon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="bg-shine">
    <div class="image">
  </div>
  </div>
```